# How to sort a List<Object> alphabetically using Object name field

Tags: java, list

I have a List of Objects like `List<Object> p`.I want to sort this list alphabetically using Object name field. Object contains 10 field and name field is one of them.

```
if (list.size() > 0) {
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Campaign>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Object object1, final Object object2) {
        return String.compare(object1.getName(), object2.getName());
        }
    } );
}
```

But there is nothing like String.compare..?

Comment: How are you going to get the name? -- `Object`s don't have names.  Do you mean using `.toString()`?

Comment: `object1` and `object2` need to be of type `Campaign`, and the compare function is `object1.getName().compareTo(object2.getName())`.

Comment: You mix `List<Object>` and `Comparator<Campaign>`. You can't do that. Either you have `List<Object>` and `Comparator<Object>` or `List<Campaign>` and `Comparator<Campaign>`

Answer (score 259, accepted):

From your code, it looks like your `Comparator` is already parameterized with `Campaign`. This will only work with `List<Campaign>`. Also, the method you're looking for is `compareTo`.

```
if (list.size() > 0) {
  Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Campaign>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(final Campaign object1, final Campaign object2) {
          return object1.getName().compareTo(object2.getName());
      }
  });
}
```

Or if you are using Java 1.8

```
list
  .stream()
  .sorted((object1, object2) -> object1.getName().compareTo(object2.getName()));
```

One final comment -- there's no point in checking the list size. Sort will work on an empty list.

Comment: I think this is the best answer that distills everything into what the OP is looking for.  And from the comments, I think he wants case-insensitive, so just switch the compareTo to compareToIgnoreCase

Comment: Minor improve in the first solution: we can do if (list.size() > 1) - as for 1 item  no need to sort..

Comment: You can use `Comparator.comparing(Campaign::getName)`

Comment: `list.sort((object1, object2) -> object1. getName().compareTo(object2. getName()));`
worked for me

Comment: @JoseDaSilva Your solution requires API 24

Comment: Try using `sortedList = list.stream().sort((object1, object2) -> object1. getName().compareTo(object2. getName()))..collect(Collectors.toList());` to get a new sorted list

Comment: @Robert B How to order a user class based on first name,middle name,last name??

Answer (score 25):

Using Java 8 [Comparator.comparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-):

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Campaign::getName));
```

Answer (score 18):

The most correct way to sort alphabetically strings is to use `Collator`, because of internationalization. Some languages have different order due to few extra characters etc.

```
   Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
   if (!list.isEmpty()) {
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Campaign>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Campaign c1, Campaign c2) {
            //You should ensure that list doesn't contain null values!
            return collator.compare(c1.getName(), c2.getName());
        }
       });
   }
```

If you don't care about internationalization use `string.compare(otherString)`.

```
   if (!list.isEmpty()) {
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Campaign>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Campaign c1, Campaign c2) {
            //You should ensure that list doesn't contain null values!
            return c1.getName().compare(c2.getName());
        }
       });
   }
```

Answer (score 13):

Have a look at `Collections.sort()` and the `Comparator` interface.

String comparison can be done with `object1.getName().compareTo(object2.getName())` or `object2.getName().compareTo(object1.getName())` (depending on the sort direction you desire).

If you want the sort to be case agnostic, do `object1.getName().toUpperCase().compareTo(object2.getName().toUpperCase())`.

Comment: and how do you suggest extracting that field called `nama` from the `Object` type? this answer is not complete.

Comment: Name extraction depends on the type of the object. I supposed it is just a placeholder type. If you cannot give a more concrete type, you might end using reflection.

Answer (score 7):

```
public class ObjectComparator implements Comparator<Object> {

    public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
        return obj1.getName().compareTo(obj2.getName());
    }

}
```

Please replace Object with your class **which contains name field**

Usage:

```
ObjectComparator comparator = new ObjectComparator();
Collections.sort(list, comparator);
```

Comment: I did this but than "tests" is coming before "Search".:(((

Comment: if you want o make reverse sorting, just replace `obj1.getName().compareTo(obj2.getName()` with `obj2.getName().compareTo(obj1.getName()` in the comparator class

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version of Robert B's answer that works for `List<T>` and sorting by a specified String property of the object using Reflection and no 3rd party libraries

```
/**
 * Sorts a List by the specified String property name of the object.
 * 
 * @param list
 * @param propertyName
 */
public static <T> void sortList(List<T> list, final String propertyName) {

    if (list.size() > 0) {
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<T>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(final T object1, final T object2) {
                String property1 = (String)ReflectionUtils.getSpecifiedFieldValue (propertyName, object1);
                String property2 = (String)ReflectionUtils.getSpecifiedFieldValue (propertyName, object2);
                return property1.compareToIgnoreCase (property2);
            }
        });
    }
}


public static Object getSpecifiedFieldValue (String property, Object obj) {

    Object result = null;

    try {
        Class<?> objectClass = obj.getClass();
        Field objectField = getDeclaredField(property, objectClass);
        if (objectField!=null) {
            objectField.setAccessible(true);
            result = objectField.get(obj);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {         
    }
    return result;
}

public static Field getDeclaredField(String fieldName, Class<?> type) {

    Field result = null;
    try {
        result = type.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }       

    if (result == null) {
        Class<?> superclass = type.getSuperclass();     
        if (superclass != null && !superclass.getName().equals("java.lang.Object")) {       
            return getDeclaredField(fieldName, type.getSuperclass());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
List< Object> myList = x.getName;
myList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Object::getName));
```

Comment: FYI if you're doing this in Android, it requires at least API level 24

Answer (score 2):

something like

```
  List<FancyObject> theList = … ;
  Collections.sort (theList,
                    new Comparator<FancyObject> ()
                    { int compare (final FancyObject a, final FancyObject d)
                          { return (a.getName().compareTo(d.getName())); }});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sortThisBy()` from [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/):

```
MutableList<Campaign> list = Lists.mutable.empty();
list.sortThisBy(Campaign::getName);
```

If you can't change the type of list from `List`:

```
List<Campaign> list = new ArrayList<>();
ListAdapter.adapt(list).sortThisBy(Campaign::getName);
```

Note: I am a contributor to Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 2):

I found another way to do the type.

```
if(listAxu.size() > 0){
    Collections.sort(listAxu, Comparator.comparing(IdentityNamed::getDescricao));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your objects has some common ancestor [let it be `T`] you should use `List<T>` instead of `List<Object>`, and implement a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for this T, using the name field.

If you don't have a common ancestor, you can implement a Comperator, and use [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) to extract the name, Note that it is unsafe, unsuggested, and suffers from bad performance to use reflection, but it allows you to access a field name without knowing anything about the actual type of the object [besides the fact that it has a field with the relevant name]

In both cases, you should use [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to sort.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming a list of `YourClass` instead of `Object`, as explained by *amit*.

You can use this bit from the Google Guava library:

```
Collections.sort(list, Ordering.natural()
  .onResultOf(new Function<String,YourClass>() {
  public String call(YourClass o) {
     return o.getName();
  }))
  .nullsLast();
```

The other answers which mention `Comparator` are not incorrect, since `Ordering` implements `Comparator`. This solution is, in my opinion, a little easier, though it may be harder if you're a beginner and not used to using libraries and/or "functional programming".

Copied shamelessly from [this answer on my own question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8415743/85821)

Comment: This is the way I'd do it, but may be too much for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Using a selection Sort

```
for(int i = list.size() - 1; i > 0; i--){

  int max = i

  for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
      if(list.get(j).getName().compareTo(list.get(j).getName()) > 0){
            max= j;
      }
  }

  //make the swap
  Object temp = list.get(i);
  list.get(i) = list.get(max);
  list.get(max) = temp;

}
```

Comment: (1) Why would he reinvent the wheel? what's wrong with `Collections.sort()`? (2) the list is of type `List<Object>`, and therefore `list.get(j).getName()` will not compile. (3) this solution is O(n^2), while using `Collections.sort()` is a better O(nlogn) solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `List<Object>` to hold objects of a subtype that has a name field (lets call the subtype `NamedObject`), you'll need to downcast the list elements in order to access the name.  You have 3 options, the best of which is the first:

1. Don't use a `List<Object>` in the first place if you can help it - keep your named objects in a `List<NamedObject>`
2. Copy your `List<Object>` elements into a `List<NamedObject>`, downcasting in the process, do the sort, then copy them back
3. Do the downcasting in the Comparator

Option 3 would look like this:

```
Collections.sort(p, new Comparator<Object> () {
        int compare (final Object a, final Object b) {
                return ((NamedObject) a).getName().compareTo((NamedObject b).getName());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(listAxu.size() > 0){
     Collections.sort(listAxu, new Comparator<Situacao>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Situacao lhs, Situacao rhs) {            
            return lhs.getDescricao().compareTo(rhs.getDescricao());
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: Care to elaborate rather than just dumping code in a 3 year old question?

Answer (score 0):

@Victor's answer worked for me and reposting it here in Kotlin in case useful to someone else doing Android.

```
if (list!!.isNotEmpty()) {
   Collections.sort(
     list,
     Comparator { c1, c2 -> //You should ensure that list doesn't contain null values!
     c1.name!!.compareTo(c2.name!!)
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
List<Campaign> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Campaign::getName));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case property contains also `NULL` values you can use:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Campaign::getName, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

This puts `NULL` values to the last positions in the ordered list.