# Sort a Java collection object based on one field in it

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have the following collection:

```
Collection<AgentSummaryDTO> agentDtoList = new ArrayList<AgentSummaryDTO>();
```

Where `AgentSummaryDTO` looks like this:

```
public class AgentSummaryDTO implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String agentName;
    private String agentCode;
    private String status;
    private Date createdDate;
    private Integer customerCount;
}
```

Now I have to sort the collection `agentDtoList` based on the `customerCount` field, how to achieve this?

Comment: If you had used those tags to search in javadoc, you could have hit this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List, java.util.Comparator)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

here is my "1liner":

```
Collections.sort(agentDtoList, new Comparator<AgentSummaryDTO>(){
   public int compare(AgentSummaryDTO o1, AgentSummaryDTO o2){
      return o1.getCustomerCount() - o2.getCustomerCount();
   }
});
```

UPDATE for Java 8:
For int  datatype

```
 Collections.sort(agentDtoList, (o1, o2) -> o1.getCustomerCount() - o2.getCustomerCount());
```

or even:

```
 Collections.sort(agentDtoList, Comparator.comparing(AgentSummaryDTO::getCustomerCount));
```

For String datatype (as in comment)

```
Collections.sort(list, (o1, o2) -> (o1.getAgentName().compareTo(o2.getAgentName())));
```

..it expects getter `AgentSummaryDTO.getCustomerCount()`

Comment: I used  return agentSummary1.getCustomerCount().compareTo(agentSummary2.getCustomerCount());

Comment: What if i need to sort same example with agentname instead of customercount? I need to sort on a string field. please suggest

Comment: @TanuGarg instead of `return o1.getCustomerCount() - o2.getCustomerCount();`, you would have `o1.getAgentName().compareTo(o2.getAgentName())`

Comment: based on the results of the `.compareTo` it can return `0` if the compared strings are the same, negative value if the first one is bigger and positive value otherwise. It uses the lexicographical ordering for strings. Then this results are used by the sorting algorithm in Java (which happens to be Merge sort)

Comment: Will `Collections.sort(agentDtoList, (o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(o1.getCustomerCount(), o2.getCustomerCount()));` work?

Comment: How to sort in descending order using this syntax `Collections.sort(agentDtoList, Comparator.comparing(AgentSummaryDTO::getCustomerCount));`

Comment: @karthik_varma_k
`Collections.sort(agentDtoList, Comparator.comparing(AgentSummaryDTO::getCustomerCount).reversed());`

Comment: there's no need for parentheses around lambda body in third example (makes it a bit easier to read :) )

Comment: Even further :             `agentDtoList.sort(Comparator.comparing(AgentSummaryDTO::getCustomerCount));`

Answer (score 15):

The [answer by Jiri Kremser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12542755/1421925) can be simplified even further, which really is the full Java 8 way to do it:

```
Collections.sort(agentDtoList, Comparator.comparing(AgentSummaryDTO::getCustomerCount));
```

This simply compares by the integer field, and works well since `Integer` implements `Comparable`.

An even cleaner solution might be to use the built-in [`comparingInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) method:

```
Collections.sort(agentDtoList, Comparator.comparingInt(AgentSummaryDTO::getCustomerCount));
```

Of course, this could be expressed even shorter by statically importing `sort` and `comparingInt`:

```
sort(agentDtoList, comparingInt(AgentSummaryDTO::getCustomerCount));
```

Answer (score 14):

for anyone who looks for answer yet:

you can also sort your list with JAVA-8 Stream-API.

```
List<AgentSummaryDTO> sortedList = agentDtoList.stream()
  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(AgentSummaryDTO::getCustomerCount).reversed())
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Since this is the only answer supporting fluent code, I think it is the best answer here

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) classes.

A simple way would be to implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface in `AgentSummaryDTO` and then pass the list to `Collections.sort()`.

If you can't edit `AgentSummaryDTO`, you need a Comparator as shown here: [How to sort a List<Object> alphabetically using Object name field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432581/how-to-sort-a-listobject-alphabetically-using-object-name-field)

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE for Java 8. It works:

```
Collections.sort(agentDtoList, (o1, o2) -> o1.getCustomerCount() - o2.getCustomerCount());
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the code below.

```
package test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class AgentSummary {
    private Long id;
    private String agentName;
    private String agentCode;
    private String status;
    private Date createdDate;
    private Integer customerCount;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AgentSummary().addObjects();   
    }

    public void addObjects(){
        List<AgentSummaryDTO> agentSummary = new ArrayList<AgentSummaryDTO>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            agentSummary.add(new AgentSummaryDTO(j));
        }
        Collections.sort(agentSummary);

        for (AgentSummaryDTO obj : agentSummary) {
            System.out.println("File " + obj.getCustomerCount());
        }
    }
}

class AgentSummaryDTO implements Serializable, Comparable<AgentSummaryDTO> {

    private Long id;
    private String agentName;
    private String agentCode;
    private String status;
    private Date createdDate;
    private Integer customerCount;

    AgentSummaryDTO() {
        customerCount = null;
    }

    AgentSummaryDTO(int customerCount) {
        this.customerCount = customerCount;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id
     *            the id to set
     */
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the agentName
     */
    public String getAgentName() {
        return agentName;
    }

    /**
     * @param agentName
     *            the agentName to set
     */
    public void setAgentName(String agentName) {
        this.agentName = agentName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the agentCode
     */
    public String getAgentCode() {
        return agentCode;
    }

    /**
     * @param agentCode
     *            the agentCode to set
     */
    public void setAgentCode(String agentCode) {
        this.agentCode = agentCode;
    }

    /**
     * @return the status
     */
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    /**
     * @param status
     *            the status to set
     */
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    /**
     * @return the createdDate
     */
    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param createdDate
     *            the createdDate to set
     */
    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return the customerCount
     */
    public Integer getCustomerCount() {
        return customerCount;
    }

    /**
     * @param customerCount
     *            the customerCount to set
     */
    public void setCustomerCount(Integer customerCount) {
        this.customerCount = customerCount;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(AgentSummaryDTO arg0) {

        if (this.customerCount > arg0.customerCount)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose class **Book** having two attributes i.e. **int pageNo** and **String bookName** with getters and setters methods. And need to sort by page numbers, below is the code,

```java
public class SortingBooks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        books.add(new Book(40, "My Dreams"));
        books.add(new Book(10, "Karma"));

        //sorting by page numbers
        books.sort((obj1, obj2) -> obj1.getPageNo()-obj2.getPageNo());

        //iterate list
        System.out.println(books.get(0).getPageNo() + "," + books.get(0).getBookName());

        //don't want to change original list then
        List<Books> sbook = books.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Book::getPageNo)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(sbook);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use this code

```
agentDtoList.sort((t1, t2) -> t1.getCustomerCount());
```

Comment: Definitely not, this is obviously completely wrong.