# Sorting beans with lambdas by comparing internal fields of type ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, spring, sorting, lambda

I have multiple Beans which have the following structure

```
@Entity
public class AttributeA implements AttributeInterface{
.....
public ZonedDateTime dateEnabled;
....
}

@Entity
public class AttributeB implements AttributeInterface {
.....
public ZonedDateTime dateEnabled;
....
}

@Entity
public class AttributeC implements AttributeInterface {
.....
public ZonedDateTime dateEnabled;
....
}
```

and I have an interface AttributeInterface which is basically is an marker for the all attributes. 
That interface implements couple of functions (more then one). What I need to do is when I have a collection of AttributesInterfaces i.e.

```
Collection<AttributeInterface> collectionObject;
```

I need to sort that collection by the field "dateEnabled" which is part of those attributes, then need to pick the latest Attribute i.e. the one that was created last, and execute an action on it for example attribute.disable().

I am new to lambdas, but I would like to use lambdas because of the parallelism they provide. However I can not figure what the construct should be  i.e. what is the most effective way of doing this. By that I mean shell i add some new method for example compareToAnotherAttributeByZonedDateTime() under the AttributeInterface and implement that method in all Attribute/A/B/C beans and then call something the solution provided here:

[Sort a Java collection object based on one field in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542185/sort-a-java-collection-object-based-on-one-field-in-it)

```
 Collections.sort(collectionObject , new Comparator<ZonedDateTime>()
            (AttributeInterface o1, AttributeInterface o2) ->
                         { 
                             return  (o1.getCustomerCount().compareToAnotherInterfaceByZonedDateTime() - o2.getCustomerCount().compareToAnotherInterfaceByZonedDateTime() );
                         } 
                     );
```

Or is there any effective way i.e. some java 8 build in functions [SAM -single abstract method or (functional interfaces)] that can do that sort of comparison for the ZonedDateTime type? By that i mean something from 
java.utils.functions

An example will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

found it for java 8

```
Collections.sort((List<AttributeInterface>) collectionObject, (obj1, obj2) -> 
                               obj1.getDateEnabled().compareTo(obj2.getDateEnabled() )    );
```