# I need to sort an jsonArray based on Average field. I am not getting any error but the sort is not working

Tags: arrays, sorting

Below is my jsonArray
[
{
"Average": "107.775",
"sum": 431.1,
"No of topUps": 4,
"MSIDN": "MSISDN2810"
},
{
"Average": "20.0",
"sum": 20,
"No of topUps": 1,
"MSIDN": "MSISDIN12390"
},
{
"Average": "22.0",
"sum": 88,
"No of topUps": 4,
"MSIDN": ""
},
{
"Average": "66.66666666666667",
"sum": 200,
"No of topUps": 3,
"MSIDN": "MS76656"
}
]

JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(array.toString());
JSONArray sortedJsonArray = new JSONArray();

```
    List<JSONObject> jsonValues = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
        jsonValues.add(jsonArr.getJSONObject(i));
    }
    Collections.sort( jsonValues, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {
        private static final String KEY_NAME = "Average";
        @Override
        public int compare(JSONObject a, JSONObject b) {
            String valA = new String();
            String valB = new String();

            valA = (String) a.get(KEY_NAME);
            valB = (String) b.get(KEY_NAME);

            return valA.compareTo(valB);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
        sortedJsonArray.put(jsonValues.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a Java collection object based on one field in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542185/sort-a-java-collection-object-based-on-one-field-in-it)

Comment: I do not have a model class , I am inserting jsonobjects by using key value pairs and then adding that json  into jsonarray  and I need that json array in sorted form based on the average field in decreasing order