# How to sort a List of Map objects?

Tags: java, list

I have a `List<Map> myList` where each map object has a key, called `priority`, and I would like to sort this list by the `priority`. I have no idea, how should I manage it.

Comment: So each map has only one pair of elements?

Comment: no. They have more key-value pairs. But each map has a key, called `priority`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a List<Object> alphabetically using Object name field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432581/how-to-sort-a-listobject-alphabetically-using-object-name-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> each map object has a key, called priority

So i guess, the maps keyset contains Strings. Also, if you want to compare the returned value for the *priority* key, then this object could implement Comparable.

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<Map<String,E extends Comparable>>(){

    @Override
    public int compare(Map<String,E extends Comparable> a, Map<String,E extends Comparable> b){
        return a.get("priority").compareTo(b.get("priority"));
        //alternative:
        //if(a.get("priority").equals(b.get("priority"))return 0;
        //if(a.get("priority") > (b.get("priority"))return 1;
        //return -1;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Map> {
  public void compare (Map m1, Map m2) {
    return ((Integer)m1.get("priority")).compareTo(m2.get("priority")));
  } 
}
// ...
list.sort(new MyComparator());`

Replace the Integer cast with another Number subclass if you are not using Integers

Answer (score 1):

If using Java8

```
myList
.stream()
.sorted((obj1, obj2) -> Integer.compare(obj1.get("Priority"), obj2.get("Priority"))
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: What is `getPriority` ?

Comment: A method that will return the priority from the object. A getter.

Comment: This is just a map right? with potentially storage as <String,Integer>

Comment: @Ajay: Edited the answer. Does it look correct now?