# UnsupportedOperationException when trying sort Sensor List

Tags: android, sorting, collections

I'm trying to receive all available sensors on the system and sort them alphabetic according sensor name.

I'm using `Collections` and `Comparator` as I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432581/how-to-sort-a-listobject-alphabetically-using-object-name-field) answer but I get `UnsupportedOperationException` error.

**The code:**

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
List<Sensor> sensorList = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
Collections.sort(sensorList, new Comparator<Sensor>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Sensor leftSensor, Sensor rightSensor) {
        return leftSensor.getName().compareTo(rightSensor.getName());
    }
});
```

The questions, why I got this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [in the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/hardware/SensorManager.java#423) (I know this is some old source code, but that will do), the returned list is [immutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html).

A fix would be to copy the list:

```
List<Sensor> sensorList = new ArrayList<Sensor>(sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL));
```

Comment: Thank you twice. 1) for the answer 2) I learn about immutable :)