# Sorting ListView in alphabetic order

Tags: android, sorting, listview

Im trying to sort my ListView in alphabetic order. ListView has 3 fields: `title, description, image`. I must sort title in alphabetic order.

Comment: Sort the contents of your data model. If you are using a `CursorAdapter`, add the appropriate sorting rule to your query (e.g., `ORDER BY` for SQLite). If you are using an `ArrayAdapter`, sort your `ArrayList` using `Collections.sort()`. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

sort your list (no the listView). try this:

```
Collections.sort(yourList, new Comparator<yourClass>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(yourClass left, yourClass right) {
        return left.getTitle().compareTo(right.getTitle());
    }
});
```

Comment: I have class Fish,for Example.I must put "Fish" instead "yourClass" or ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>   ?

Comment: Yes. btw, FTI, if the returned list is  immutable you should storage the result in new variable. see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32328630/unsupportedoperationexception-when-trying-sort-sensor-list