# how to sort custom item bean array list in alphabetical order in android

Tags: android

Actually I have a list view , how can I sort list items alphabetical order how can i change positions based on name of items.

By using array list we can do but how can we do sort for bean list

Listview:

ItemsBean bean1 = new ItemsBean();

```
            bean1.setItemnNameDisplay(items.getString("Prodname"));
            bean1.setParentobjectid(items.getString("ParentObjectID"));
            bean1.setObjectid(items.getString("ObjectID"));
            bean1.setQuantityDisplay(items.getInt("Quantity"));
            bean1.setProdnum(items.getInt("ProdNum"));

            bean1.setLinenum(line);


            itemsList1.add(bean1);
```

Comment: Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8432848/2910520).
If that doesn't work for you, pls post some code showing your list structure or we won't able to help further

Comment: @android You can use Comparable and Comparator classes to achive such thing. pls. google out.

Comment: i edited my code pls check it

Answer (score 0):

In `ItemBean` class implement `Comparable` interface and override `compareTo()` method:

```
class ItemsBean implements Comparable{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
    ItemsBean item = (ItemsBean) o;
        return this.itemnNameDisplay.compareTo(item.itemnNameDisplay);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Collections.sort(swaplistswap, new Comparator() {

public int compare(ItemsBean one, ItemsBean other) {

```
        return one.getItemnNameDisplay().compareTo(other.getItemnNameDisplay());
               // return one.getQuantityDisplay()-(other.getQuantityDisplay());

            }
        });
```