# What is the right way to sort my ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I have a custom class called "ergebnisse" with several fields, one of them is *score* of type `Long`.

I want to sort an `ArrayList<ergebnisse>` by score.
I tried a lot of things, but most most are fore one or two columns.

```
ArrayList<ergebnisse> list = new ArrayList<ergebnisse>();
Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.fetchNamesByConstraint(filter);
while(data.moveToNext()){
    //get the value from the database in column 1
    //then add it to the ArrayList
    String name = data.getString(1);
    String scorestring = data.getString(2);
    Long score=Long.parseLong(scorestring);
    String timestring = data.getString(3);
    Double time= Double.parseDouble(timestring);
    String mode = data.getString(5);
    String game = data.getString(4);
    String levstring = data.getString(6);
    Integer lev=Integer.parseInt(levstring);
    list.add(new ergebnisse(name,score,time,mode,lev,game));
}
```

I want to sort from highest to lowest score.

Comment: Where is the code to sort?

Comment: Related: [How to sort a List<Object> alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432581/how-to-sort-a-listobject-alphabetically-using-object-name-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in many ways.

Method 1(Traditional):

your custom class

```
public class Ergebnisse {

    private String name;
    private Long score;

   //standard getters and setters
}
```

implement comparator interface by overriding compare method

```
class SortbyScore implements Comparator<Ergebnisse> { 
    @Override
    public int compare(Ergebnisse a, Ergebnisse b) { 
    return b.getScore() - a.getScore(); 
    } 
}
```

Then whenever you want list to be sorted by score use

```
Collections.sort(list, new SortbyScore());
```

Method 2(Java 8 or above):

Simply use lambda expresson

```
list.sort((o1, o2) -> o2.getScore().compareTo(o1.getScore()));
```

*Do note that its important to use wrapper class of primitive type long(Long) to store score variable for this to work!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a custom comparison function to sort:

```
Collections.sort(
    list,
    (a, b) -> Integer.compare(b.score, a.score)
);
```

You'll notice `b.score` is the first arg to `Integer.compare`. That reverses the meaning of the comparison so that the list will be in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if we have a class:

```
  private class Person{
    private String name;
    private Long score;
  }
```

Then we can compare like:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getScore));
```

or

```
list.sort((person1, person2) -> person1.getScore().compareTo(person2.getScore()));
```