# array doesn't automatically sort comparable objects

Tags: java

I have a class box with 3 double values. The task is to sort one of the values and print the results. Below there  is a code

```
 public class Box implements Comparable<Box> {

        private double x;
        private double y;
        private double z;
        private double volume;

@Override
    public int compareTo(Box o) {
        return this.x > o.x ? 1 : this.x < o.x ? -1 : 0;
    }

    public static void  sorting (Box[] o)
    {
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i<o.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(o[i].x);
        }
    }
```

There is no errors in this code, but it is not sorting x parameter too.

Comment: You should post your [mcve] so we can see where you actually do the sort, where you call `Arrays.sort(boxes);`, etc.

Comment: well ... you never actually call or implement a sort. what exactly do you expect? your sorting method will just print out what's there, that's all

Comment: oh yeas, thanks,  added Arrays.sort(o); in sorting function, ok now

Comment: You might want to delete this question

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Java are not automatically sorted (nor are collections in general). For arrays you need to call

```
Arrays.sort(boxes);
```

If working with collections you can either sort an existing List with

```
Collections.sort(boxList);
```

Or use a [SortedSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedSet.html)/[Map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html) instead (e.g. [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html)). These types of collections will automatically order their elements on insertion and maintain the natural order.

As pointed out by @AndyTurner Sets and Maps will of course discard duplicates (depending on your implementation of `hashCode` and `equals`) which might be something you don't want.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725387/why-is-there-no-sortedlist-in-java) and it's very good answer is also related and provides a good overview of sorting collections in Java in general.

Comment: "These types of collections will automatically order" but they will also discard duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing `Comparable` only means that class provides some **default** order for its instances. *It **doesn't** mean that every array or collection must **automatically** apply that order*.

For instance `String` class also implements `Comparable` which provides *lexicographical* order, but you are still able to decide where your string should be placed in array. It is possible because when you do

```
array[index] = element;
```

decision of where `element` will be placed depends **only** on `index`, not on any characteristic of `element`.

To sort array using *default* order of its elements you can use `Arrays.sort(o);`, otherwise your array `o` will hold elements in positions specified by indexes.

Answer (score -1):

You actually have few different options. Some of them are creating you own sorting function as it was mentioned, or use a Collection sorting with a proper Comparator. You may want to check [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432581/how-to-sort-a-listobject-alphabetically-using-object-name-field) to get some more details of the topic. Also, remember to use search before you post, it was the first thing to pop out after typing "java sort by object field" or something like that.