# Merge sort generates arbitrary order when implemented with strings

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

I am writing a program for an assignment, but when I tried to adapt merge sort to work on a String (to sort alphabetically), it generates a seemingly random order of titles, as seen below. I asked this question some time ago, and got no real answers, and so I felt like I needed to phrase it better and include my full code.

By Title Ascending

```
Titanic, 1997 by Paramount, Marvel's The Avengers, 2012 by Disney  
Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2, 2012 by Warner Brothers  
Furious 7, 2015 by Universal  
Avengers: Age of Ultron, 2015 by Disney  
Avatar, 2009 by Fox  
Star Wars: The Force Awakens, 2015 by Disney  
Jurassic World, 2015 by Universal  
Avengers: Infinity War, 2018 by Disney  
Black Panther, 2018 by Disney
```

I have to arrange alphabetically specifically using merge sort that I write myself, and while I have tried all sorts of different configurations of the compareTo statement, like:

```
else if ((a[j].getTitle()).compareTo(a[i].getTitle()) > 0)
else if ((a[i].getTitle()).compareTo(a[j].getTitle()) < 0)
else if ((a[i].getTitle()).compareTo(a[j].getTitle()) > 0)
```

none of them work.

```
/**
 * Write a description of class MovieV3Tester here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class MovieV3Tester
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        MovieV3 [] movies = {new MovieV3 ("Avatar", 2009, "Fox"), 
                           new MovieV3 ("Titanic", 1997, "Paramount"), 
                           new MovieV3 ("Star Wars: The Force Awakens", 2015, "Disney"),
                           new MovieV3 ("Avengers: Infinity War", 2018, "Disney"),
                           new MovieV3 ("Jurassic World", 2015, "Universal"),
                           new MovieV3 ("Marvel's The Avengers", 2012, "Disney"),
                           new MovieV3 ("Furious 7", 2015, "Universal"),
                           new MovieV3 ("Avengers: Age of Ultron", 2015, "Disney"),
                           new MovieV3 ("Black Panther", 2018, "Disney"),
                           new MovieV3 ("Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2", 2012, "Warner Brothers")
                           };
    System.out.println("Original\n");
    print(movies);
    System.out.println("\nBy Title Ascending\n");
    mergeTitle(movies, 0, (movies.length-1));
    mergeTitle(movies, 0, (movies.length-1));
    print(movies);
    System.out.println("\nBy Year Ascending\n");
    mergeYear(movies, 0, (movies.length-1));
    print(movies);
}
public static void print(MovieV3 [] movies)
{
    for(MovieV3 movie : movies)
    {
        System.out.println(movie.getTitle() + ", " + movie.getYear() + " by " + movie.getStudio());
    }
}
public static void merge( MovieV3[] a, int low, int mid, int high, int compare)
{
    MovieV3[] temp = new MovieV3[ high - low + 1 ];

    int i = low, j = mid + 1, n = 0;
    if(compare == 1)
    {
    while( i <= mid || j <= high )
    {
        if( i > mid )
        {
            temp[ n ] = a[ j ];
            j++;
        }
        else if( j > high )
        {
            temp[ n ] = a[ i ];
            i++;
        }
        else if( a[ i ].getYear() < a[ j ].getYear() )
        {
            temp[ n ] = a[ i ];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            temp[ n ] = a[ j ];
            j++;
        }
        n++;
    }
    }
    else if(compare ==2)
    {
        while( i <= mid || j <= high )
    {
        if( i > mid )
        {
            temp[ n ] = a[ j ];
            j++;
        }
        else if( j > high )
        {
            temp[ n ] = a[ i ];
            i++;
        }
        else if((a[ j ].getTitle()).compareTo(a[i].getTitle())< 0)
        {
            temp[ n ] = a[ i ];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            temp[ n ] = a[ j ];
            j++;
        }
        n++;
    }
    }
    else
    {
        while( i <= mid || j <= high )
    {
        if( i > mid )
        {
            temp[ n ] = a[ j ];
            j++;
        }
        else if( j > high )
        {
            temp[ n ] = a[ i ];
            i++;
        }
        else if( a[ i ].getYear() < a[ j ].getYear() )
        {
            temp[ n ] = a[ i ];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            temp[ n ] = a[ j ];
            j++;
        }
        n++;
    }
    }
    for( int k = low ; k <= high ; k++ )
        a[ k ] = temp[ k - low ];
} // end of merge
public static void mergeYear(MovieV3[] a, int low, int high)
{
    if( low == high )
        return;

    int mid = ( low + high ) / 2;

    mergeYear( a, low, mid );       // recursive call
    mergeYear( a, mid + 1, high);   // recursive call

    //Debugging Statements 
    //uncomment to print the listings after each pass through the sort
    //System.out.println("\nCurrent list");
    //for(Movie h : a)  
    //    if( h != null) System.out.printf("$%10.2f \n", h.getCost() );

    merge( a, low, mid, high, 1);
}

public static void mergeTitle(MovieV3[] a, int low, int high)
{
    if( low == high )
        return;

    int mid = ( low + high ) / 2;

    mergeYear( a, low, mid );       // recursive call
    mergeYear( a, mid + 1, high);   // recursive call

    //Debugging Statements 
    //uncomment to print the listings after each pass through the sort
    //System.out.println("\nCurrent list");
    //for(Movie h : a)  
    //    if( h != null) System.out.printf("$%10.2f \n", h.getCost() );

    merge( a, low, mid, high, 2);
}
public static MovieV3 [] insertionTitle(MovieV3[] source,int compare)
{
   MovieV3[] dest = new MovieV3[ source.length ];

    for( int i = 0 ; i < source.length ; i++ )
    {
        MovieV3 next = source[ i ];
        int insertIndex = 0;
        int k = i;
        while( k > 0 && insertIndex == 0 )
        {
            if(compare == 1)
            {
            if( next.getTitle().compareTo( dest[k-1].getTitle() ) > 0 )
            {
                insertIndex = k;
            }
            else
            {
                dest[ k ] = dest[ k - 1 ];
            }
            }
            else
            {
            if( next.getTitle().compareTo( dest[k-1].getTitle() ) < 0 )
            {
                insertIndex = k;
            }
            else
            {
                dest[ k ] = dest[ k - 1 ];
            }  
            }
            k--;
        }

        dest[ insertIndex ] = next;

        //Debugging Statements 
        //uncomment to print the listings after each pass through the sort
        //System.out.println("\nPass # " + i);
        //for(MovieV3 h : dest)  
        //    if( h != null) System.out.printf("%-15s \n", h.getCity() );
    } // end of for
    return dest;
}
```

}

Hopefully, it will eventually output the following

```
Avatar, 2009 by Fox, 
Avengers: Age of Ultron, 2015 by Disney, 
Avengers: Infinity War, 2018 by Disney, 
Black Panther, 2018 by Disney, 
Furious 7, 2015 by Universal, 
Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2, 2012 by Warner Brothers, 
Jurassic World, 2015 by Universal, 
Marvel's The Avengers, 2012 by Disney, 
Star Wars: The Force Awakens, 2015 by Disney, 
Titanic, 1997 by Paramount
```

This program sorts ints just fine, it's the String sort that doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432581/how-to-sort-a-listobject-alphabetically-using-object-name-field is a very identical question and you find a lot of interresting info there to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your program was correct; there were just a few minor errors.

This is the version of your code with minor fixes and annotation:

```
public class MovieV3Tester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MovieV3[] movies = {
            new MovieV3 ("Avatar", 2009, "Fox"), 
            new MovieV3 ("Titanic", 1997, "Paramount"), 
            new MovieV3 ("Star Wars: The Force Awakens", 2015, "Disney"),
            new MovieV3 ("Avengers: Infinity War", 2018, "Disney"),
            new MovieV3 ("Jurassic World", 2015, "Universal"),
            new MovieV3 ("Marvel's The Avengers", 2012, "Disney"),
            new MovieV3 ("Furious 7", 2015, "Universal"),
            new MovieV3 ("Avengers: Age of Ultron", 2015, "Disney"),
            new MovieV3 ("Black Panther", 2018, "Disney"),
            new MovieV3 ("Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2", 2012, "Warner Brothers")
        };

        System.out.println("Original\n");
        print(movies);
        System.out.println("\nBy Title Ascending\n");
        mergeTitle(movies, 0, (movies.length-1)); 
        // Removed extra unnecessary call to `mergeTitle()`
        print(movies);
        System.out.println("\nBy Year Ascending\n");
        mergeYear(movies, 0, (movies.length-1));
        print(movies);
    }

    public static void print(MovieV3[] movies)
    {
        for (MovieV3 movie : movies)
        {
            System.out.println(movie.getTitle() + ", " + movie.getYear() + " by " + movie.getStudio());
        }
    }

    public static void merge(MovieV3[] a, int low, int mid, int high, int compare)
    {
        MovieV3[] temp = new MovieV3[high - low + 1];

        int i = low, j = mid + 1, n = 0;
        // Changed from `compare == 1` to this so that the last `else` block could be 
        // removed, as it was identical to this first block
        if (compare != 2)
        {
            while (i <= mid || j <= high)
            {
                if (i > mid)
                {
                    temp[n] = a[j];
                    j++;
                }
                else if (j > high)
                {
                    temp[n] = a[i];
                    i++;
                }
                else if (a[i].getYear() < a[j].getYear())
                {
                    temp[n] = a[i];
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp[n] = a[j];
                    j++;
                }
                n++;
            }
        }
        else if (compare == 2)
        {
            while (i <= mid || j <= high)
            {
                if (i > mid)
                {
                    temp[n] = a[j];
                    j++;
                }
                else if (j > high)
                {
                    temp[n] = a[i];
                    i++;
                }
                // Changed the operator from `<` to `>` so that the titles are printed 
                // the way you showed in your post
                else if ((a[j].getTitle()).compareTo(a[i].getTitle()) > 0)
                {
                    temp[n] = a[i];
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp[n] = a[j];
                    j++;
                }
                n++;
            }
        }

        for (int k = low ; k <= high ; k++)
            a[k] = temp[k - low];

    } // end of merge

    public static void mergeYear(MovieV3[] a, int low, int high)
    {
        if (low == high)
            return;

        int mid = (low + high) / 2;

        mergeYear(a, low, mid);       // recursive call
        mergeYear(a, mid + 1, high);   // recursive call

        merge(a, low, mid, high, 1);
    }

    public static void mergeTitle(MovieV3[] a, int low, int high)
    {
        if (low == high)
            return;

        int mid = (low + high) / 2;

        // I'm not sure if it was just a typo but in your code you had called `mergeYear()` 
        // twice instead of `mergeTitle()`, which was causing the sorting to not work
        mergeTitle(a, low, mid);       // recursive call
        mergeTitle(a, mid + 1, high);   // recursive call

        merge(a, low, mid, high, 2);
    }
}
```

Even though the edits are minor and you basically had the right code in place, hopefully this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

A minor mistake in mergeTitle method

```
public static void mergeTitle(MovieV3[] a, int low, int high)
{
    ....

    mergeYear( a, low, mid );       // recursive call
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -> should be mergeTitle    
    mergeYear( a, mid + 1, high);   // recursive call        
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -> should be mergeTitle

    ....

    merge( a, low, mid, high, 2);
}
```